# Override a general CSS style for an individual item?

Tags: css, styles

Sorry if the title is a little vague.  I wasn't quite sure how to word this question.  I currently have a style:

```
#exampleTable th {
background-color: #333;
}
```

The style applies to a particular table's header tags as you can see.  My question is how do I change an individual header in this table's background color to something else?  An attribute doesn't work because it is getting overridden by my general style.  How can I accomplish this?  Thanks.

Comment: [An inline style would not be overridden by the general style](http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/rr6LN/)

Comment: AFAIK, inline style has the highest priority. Can you demonstrate why an inline style "doesn't work"?

Comment: My bad I didn't mean inline style.  I meant attribute.

Comment: And that actually made me realize I should have been using a style not an attribute.  Lol.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `!important` in your inline style, it should work:

```
<th style="background-color: red !important">
```

Comment: inline styles should never be used.. it's the whole separation of style and document structure thingie.. just use a more specific css selector

Comment: @abbood original question asked about inline style.

Answer (score 0):

Is the CSS in an external document (.css file)? If so, an inline style would overwrite it. You could do something lJava Templating Classike:

```
<table class='someclass'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th style='background-color: red;'></th>
            ....
```

However, I think using a class would be more efficient. You just have to make your class rule more specific than your generic th rule. For example

```
#exampleTable th {
background-color: #333;
}
#exampleTable th.myclass {background-color: #00f;}
```

Now any th with the class `myclass` will be red, while th without the class will be dark gray.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care for compatibility with old browsers (especially IE) you can use the 
:nth-child() pseudo-class

```
#exampleTable th:nth-child(3){color:green}
```

http://tinyurl.com/aogul8e

Read more: http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

If you want to support old browser follow Mike's suggestion and add a class for each TH you want to override (or use jQuery to make use of nth-child with cross-browser compatibility)

Use of "!important" should be only for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Using an attribute selector works fine if you just use a combined selector that has high enough [specificity](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/specificity). For example, use `<th class=foo>...</th>` for the cell and a CSS rule like

```
#exampleTable th.foo {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Here the selector has one more ingredient, the class selector `.foo`, than your general rule. This ensures higher specificity.